# List all values if one condition per criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f90ae289b7a67ed3359f3209a0dd5ee9)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    supplier VARCHAR(255),
    supplier_rating VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(campaign, supplier, supplier_rating, quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "Supplier_A", "high", "300"),
("C001", "Supplier_D", "high", "420"),
("C001", "Supplier_F", "low", "200"),

("C002", "Supplier_L", "high", "910"),
("C002", "Supplier_B", "mid", "370"),

("C003", "Supplier_Z", "mid", "136"),
("C003", "Supplier_M", "low", "247"),
("C003", "Supplier_C", "high", "496");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
     campaign    |     supplier      |     supplier_rating
-----------------|-------------------|-----------------------------
    C001         |    Supplier_A     |     high
    C001         |    Supplier_D     |     high
    C001         |    Supplier_F     |     low
-----------------|-------------------|-----------------------------
    C003         |    Supplier_Z     |     mid
    C003         |    Supplier_M     |     low
    C003         |    Supplier_C     |     high
```

---

In the above example I want to query all `campaigns` that contain a `supplier` with a `supplier_rating` with `low`. 
All `campaigns` that fullfill this condition should be listed with their corresponding `supplier` and `supplier_rating` in the result.

---

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT 
campaign,
supplier,
supplier_rating,
(CASE WHEN MAX(supplier_rating = 'low') OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) = 1
THEN 'low' ELSE supplier_rating END) AS supplier_evaluation2
FROM operations;
```

It comes close to the result but instead of showing each `supplier_rating` per `supplier` it displays `low` for all `suppliers` per `campaign` and it also does not exclude `C002`.

How do I need to modify this query to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just a where that is missing? Or am I missing something?

```
SELECT 
campaign,
supplier,
supplier_rating

FROM operations

WHERE campaign IN (SELECT campaign FROM operations WHERE supplier_rating = 'low')
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4bfcd8a8488355e33b9271ceb87ba82d

Answer (score 2):

you can use exists

```
SELECT 
campaign,
supplier,
supplier_rating    
FROM operations t1    
WHERE exists  (SELECT 1 FROM operations t2 WHERE t1.campaign = t2.campaign
                        and t2.supplier_rating = 'low')
```